# cannot reslove method android studio disconnect and (R.id.map)

Tags: java, android

I'm still really new at working on applications in Java. All went well till I reached an issue. The disconnect under the protected void on Stop and the (R.id.map)) .getMap as it comes up with an error saying cannot resolve method for disconnect and cannot reslove symbol for map. 
I'm currently working through http://paulusworld.com/technical/android-geofences which is brilliant tutorial if anyone ever decides they want to have a look :) Thank you in advise guys!

```
package com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnCameraChangeListener {

    /**
     * Google Map object
     */
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    /**
     * Geofence Data
     */

    /**
     * Geofences Array
     */
    ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofences;

    /**
     * Geofence Coordinates
     */
    ArrayList<LatLng> mGeofenceCoordinates;

    /**
     * Geofence Radius'
     */
    ArrayList<Integer> mGeofenceRadius;

    /**
     * Geofence Store
     */
    private GeofenceStore mGeofenceStore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        // Initializing variables
        mGeofences = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        mGeofenceCoordinates = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        mGeofenceRadius = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Adding geofence coordinates to array.
        mGeofenceCoordinates.add(new LatLng(43.042861, -87.911559));
        mGeofenceCoordinates.add(new LatLng(43.042998, -87.909753));
        mGeofenceCoordinates.add(new LatLng(43.040732, -87.921364));
        mGeofenceCoordinates.add(new LatLng(43.039912, -87.897038));

        // Adding associated geofence radius' to array.
        mGeofenceRadius.add(100);
        mGeofenceRadius.add(50);
        mGeofenceRadius.add(160);
        mGeofenceRadius.add(160);


        // Bulding the geofences and adding them to the geofence array.

        // Performing Arts Center
        mGeofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("Performing Arts Center")
                        // The coordinates of the center of the geofence and the radius in meters.
                .setCircularRegion(mGeofenceCoordinates.get(0).latitude, mGeofenceCoordinates.get(0).longitude, mGeofenceRadius.get(0).intValue())
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                        // Required when we use the transition type of GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                .setLoiteringDelay(30000)
                .setTransitionTypes(
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                                | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                                | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build());

        // Starbucks
        mGeofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("Starbucks")
                        // The coordinates of the center of the geofence and the radius in meters.
                .setCircularRegion(mGeofenceCoordinates.get(1).latitude, mGeofenceCoordinates.get(1).longitude, mGeofenceRadius.get(1).intValue())
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                        // Required when we use the transition type of GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                .setLoiteringDelay(30000)
                .setTransitionTypes(
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                                | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
                                | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build());

        // Milwaukee Public Museum
        mGeofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("Milwaukee Public Museum")
                        // The coordinates of the center of the geofence and the radius in meters.
                .setCircularRegion(mGeofenceCoordinates.get(2).latitude, mGeofenceCoordinates.get(2).longitude, mGeofenceRadius.get(2).intValue())
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                                | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build());

        // Milwaukee Art Museum
        mGeofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("Milwaukee Art Museum")
                        // The coordinates of the center of the geofence and the radius in meters.
                .setCircularRegion(mGeofenceCoordinates.get(3).latitude, mGeofenceCoordinates.get(3).longitude, mGeofenceRadius.get(3).intValue())
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                                | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT).build());

        // Add the geofences to the GeofenceStore object.
        mGeofenceStore = new GeofenceStore(this, mGeofences);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGeofenceStore.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this),
                    this, 0);
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
        // map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the
     * camera. In this case, we just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap}
     * is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        // Centers the camera over the building and zooms int far enough to
        // show the floor picker.
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                43.039634, -87.908395), 14));

        // Hide labels.
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        // Makes sure the visuals remain when zoom changes.
        for(int i = 0; i < mGeofenceCoordinates.size(); i++) {
            mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(mGeofenceCoordinates.get(i))
                    .radius(mGeofenceRadius.get(i).intValue())
                    .fillColor(0x40ff0000)
                    .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT).strokeWidth(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `disconnect` is not implemented in this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

go to `file-> Invalidate caches/Restart`. that would do the problem in 95% cases,
in another 5%, try bringing in your source file closer to the root folder, in many case it is `C:/` . Just copy paste your project folder and paste it in `C`